# Popup window in OS X App

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I have a little problem with app and looking for the best solution. I want to create an popup window that have separate logic in other NSViewController.

The case is - I click on the button in my window and then other window appears with some NSTextField's and custom design. I'm considering what component is the best for my issue.

something like this:

[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqIww.png)

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: `NSPanel` or create another window? Have you looked at the [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031i)?

Comment: You could just link the button which should open the window to a viewcontroller by control dragging from the button to the the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

If have done it with the following code:

```
let addMyPopover = NSPopover()

if let popOverController = aViewController(xyz: data) {
            popOverController.closeDelegate = self
            addMyPopover.behavior = .Transient
            addMyPopover.contentViewController = popOverController
            addMyPopover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 380)
            addMyPopover.showRelativeToRect(addButton.bounds,    ofView: addPhaseButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)
        }

extension MyController: closeViewDelegate {
    func closePopover(sender: AnyObject?) {
       addMyPopover.performClose(sender)
    }
} 

protocol closeViewDelegate: class {
   func closePopover(sender: AnyObject?)
}
```

aViewController is from type NSViewController

Comment: It's not exactly what I need (see screenshot)

Comment: I thing thats the way Apple suggest to use: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH52-SW1

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func showPopover(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let vcPopover = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerPop") as! NSViewController
    self.presentViewController(vcPopover, asPopoverRelativeTo : sender.bounds, of : sender, preferredEdge: .maxY, behavior: .transient)
}
```

[image]